# Cannot find z variable (3D Points - Java 24 hours)

Tags: java, 3d, point, points

I've just started learning Java so sorry if this is a noob question but I've been through each line of code and I don't understand what's going wrong. The code is from the book "Java in 24 hours".

The aim of the code is to take a starting 2D and 3D point, then move them and translate them. First it asks me to make a 3D point class:

```
package com.java24hours;

import java.awt.*;

public class Point3D extends Point
{
    public int z;

    public Point3D(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        super(x,y);
        this.z = z;
    }
    public void move(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        this.z = z;
        super.move(x,y);
    }
    public void translate(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        this.z += z;
        super.translate(x,y);
    }
}
```

It then calls for a tester class which uses the Points3D to move and translate the 3D points:

```
package com.java24hours;

import java.awt.*;

class PointTester
{
    public static void main(String[] arguments)
    {
        Point location1 = new Point(11,22);
        Point location2 = new Point3D(7,6,64);       

        System.out.println("The 2D point is at ("+location1.x + "," + location1.y +")");

        System.out.println("It's being moved to (4,11)");
        location1.move(4,11);
        System.out.println("The 2D point is now at (" + location1.x + "," + location1.y + ")");

        System.out.println("It's now being moved -10 in both the x and y axis");
        location1.translate(-10,-10);
        System.out.println("The 2D point is now at (" + location1.x +"," + location1.y + ")\n");

        System.out.println("The 3D point is at (" + location2.x + "," + location2.y + "," + location.z + ")");

        System.out.println("It's being moved to (10,22,71)");
        location2.move(10,22,71);
        System.out.println("The 3D point is now at (" + location2.x + "," + location2.y + "," + location2.z + ")");

        System.out.println("It's now going to be moved -20 units in the x y and z axis");
        location2.translate(-20,-20,-20);
        System.out.println("It's now at (" + location2.x + "," + location2.y + "," + location2.z + ")");
    }
}
```

This creates the following errors on the lines featuring location2.z:

cannot find symbol
method move cannot be applied to given types
method translate cannot be applied to given types

Source is here:
https://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=STY_Java2_24hours&seqNum=140

This is roughly what it should give me (I changed some of the wording):

```
The 2D point is located at (11, 22) 
    It's being moved to (4, 13) 
The 2D point is now at (4, 13) 
    It's being moved -10 units on both the x and y axes 
The 2D point ends up at (-6, 3) 

The 3D point is located at (7, 6, 64) 
    It's being moved to (10, 22, 71) 
The 3D point is now at (10, 22, 71) 
    It's being moved -20 units on the x, y and z axes 
The 3D point ends up at (-10, 2, 51)
```

I think my confusion is that I declared the z variable in the Point3D class, I created the newPoint3D which accepted three variables, and then when I try and use the third variable later on it can't find it.

Thanks

Comment: Declare the variable as `Point3D location2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax problem in your code because you are using `location.z` instead of `location2.z`

Also, you are using `Point` class as a reference to create an object of `Point3D`. You cannot access variable `z` from a `Point` class due to **Polymorphism concepts**(I suggest you look into it) as the `Point3D` inherits the `Point` class and so, the variable `z` is defined within the `Point3D` class and not the `Point`.

Concluding, you should instantiate your *3D Point* as below:

```
Point3D location2 = new Point3D(7,6,64);
```

Comment: Good eye! This is half of his problem.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison just rectified the other half ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you've declared your `location2` variable as a Point.  Its real type is Point3D, but you're referencing it as type Point and so Point3D variable z is not visible.  (This is a fundamental principal of object oriented programming called polymorphism, but don't worry about that yet as you're just starting to learn!)

You can fix this by declaring your `location2` variable as a Point3D, like so:

```
Point location1 = new Point(11,22);

//here's the fixed line of code.
Point3D location2 = new Point3D(7,6,64);

//[...] rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the base `Point`'s `move()` method accepts two parameters. However, you're calling that method with three: `location2.move(10,22,71);`

Sure, *you* know that the `Point` contained in `location2` is actually a `Point3D`, but the compiler thinks it's just a regular `Point`. Change the type of `location2` to `Point3D` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
    Point location2 = new Point3D(7,6,64);
```

You have created a `Point3D` instance and assigned it to a `Point` variable.  The object that is currently in `location2` at that point has a `z` field, but since you declared the variable as a `Point` ... the compiler has to assume that it is a `Point` instance, which doesn't have a `z` field.

Hence the compiler tells you that `location2.z` is a compilation error.

The fix is this:

```
    Point3D location2 = new Point3D(7,6,64);
```

---

OK, so why is Java designed to not allow that?

Consider an example like this:

```
    Point location2 = test ? new Point3D(7,6,64) : new Point(7,6);
    System.out.println(location2.z);
```

If the compiler accepted that, and `test` was `false`, what should happen?  In a dynamically typed language, that would give you a runtime error because you attempted to access a field that does not exist.  But Java is statically typed by design, and that is not acceptable.

In fact, Java takes the view that when you declare a variable has a type `Point` the following code can only treat its value as a `Point`.

Comment: All excellent answers! I got it working now! Thank you very much for all your input!

Answer (score 0):

Either define 'x' and 'move' in Point or refer to location1 and location2 by Point3D